# GitHub repository

Tags: repository, git-pull, pull-request

I have searched GitHub to access the log details of pull request using the following: `repo:organisation/repository`

But couldn't get the pull requests of individual user.
How to access the log of *pull requests* of all users in **GitHub** repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see contributors to a repository, click the "contributors" link near the top of the page.

If you want to see who has done pull requests, click the pull requests tab. To see all pull requests go to the filter search bar and remove the text "is:open" and hit enter. This will show you all pull requests.

I am not sure that the exact functionality you are looking for exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GitHub API: [List Pull Requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/pulls
```

See [this perl script for instance](https://gist.github.com/ctrueden/4156679#file-github-pr-comments-pl-L15-L17), which lists the PRs of a repo.

```perl
my $urlPrefix = "https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo";
my @prs = `curl -s $urlPrefix/pulls | grep '\"number\"'`;
```